# zip or tar the resulting files with command "git status" over modified files. Linux

Tags: linux, git, zip, stdout, tar

Recently, i've been searching how to compress the *git status modified files* on command line linux. This git status before git add and git commit commands.

```
$ git status
.
.
modified:   app/model/solicitud/Solicitud.js
modified:   app/view/basura/Grilla.js
modified:   app/view/excepcion/Grilla.js
modified:   app/view/modulo/Contenedor.js
modified:   app/view/modulo/Grilla.js
.
.
```

So, i came with this solutions, to .tar.gz and zip respectively:

```
$ git status |grep -i "modified:" |cut -d':' -f2 |tee |tr -d " " | tar -T - -zcvf ~/myfolderdesttar/myfile.tar.gz
$ git status |grep -i "modified:" |cut -d':' -f2 |tee |tr -d " " | zip ~/myfolderdestzip/myzipfile.zip -@
```

¿Do you have a shorter solution to this or a better way with git command?.
Thanks.

Comment: At least you can replace `grep -i "modified:" | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d " " | tee` with `awk '/modified:/ { print $2 }' | tee` (case-sensitive, though). Not much of an improvement, but it would spawn less processes.

Comment: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M` can list the modified files. Have a look at `git diff --help`.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. In response to ElpieKay, thanks for the advise, now when i do **git add .**, i can later do **git diff --name-only --diff-filter=MACR | nl** to count the change made, or without nl to take all the changes, except the deleted ones and proceed to compress.

Answer (score 0):

to tar modified files:

```
git status | grep modified | awk '{print $3}' | xargs tar cvf modified.tar
```

to tar new files:

```
git status | grep new | awk '{print $3}' | xargs tar cvf new.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a tar of modified and newly added files:

**Command 1**

`(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) | sort -u | xargs tar cvf modified.tar`

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M` : Lists the modified files.

`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` : Lists untracked files.

`sort -u` : Sorts and removes duplicates.

`xargs tar cvf modified.tar` : Creates the tarball.

**Command 2**

`git status -s | awk '{print $2}' | xargs tar cvf modified.tar --exclude='node_modules'`